# Ant conditionally set attribute

Tags: ant

Is it possible to have a dynamically set attribute in Ant?

At the moment all of our wars have the same name: "mywar.war". I'd like to have wars built with JDK6 to be "mywar-1.6.war" and those built with JDK7 to still just be "mywar.war".

Currently:

```
<war warfile="${dist.dir}/mywar.war">
..
<war />
```

I can include the Java version like this:

```
<war warfile="${dist.dir}/mywar-${ant.java.version}.war">
```

But what I'd like to have is the logic to do something like this:

```
if (${ant.java.version} == "1.6") {
  war.name="mywar-${ant.java.version}";
} else {
  war.name="mywar";
}

<war warfile="${dist.dir}/${war.name}.war">
```

Is there a correct way to go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set properties conditionally is to use [the `condition` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html):

```
<condition property="war.suffix" value="-1.6" else="">
  <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.6"/>
</condition>

<war warfile="${dist.dir}/mywar${war.suffix}.war">
```

The trick here is that the `else=""` means that `war.suffix` will be an empty string on any version other than 1.6.

Comment: Man, ant has some strange syntax, but it is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use some thing like that but it's not available in ant as such. You will have to download ant-contrib.jar

And then you have some thing like this

```
<if>
 <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.6" />
 <then>
   war.name="mywar-${ant.java.version}";
 </then>
 <else>
   war.name="mywar";
 </else>
</if>
```

[See this link for ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html)

Comment: I like this syntax a lot better than what's built in, but I'm trying to avoid adding an extra jar.

Comment: Downvote because it goes straight to ant-contrib without considering the <condition> approach - it's incorrect to say "you can't"